# How to make an image popup on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So my incremental has come a long way, I got assistance here to make the original popup and it works great, now i really want to make the popup an image?

so far i have:

```
$("#coffeeButton").click(function(e) {
    var obj = $("#clone").clone();
    $("body").append(obj);
    obj.html("+"+ cookRate);
    coffee += cookRate;
    totalCoffee += cookRate;
    document.getElementById("coffee").innerHTML = prettify(coffee);
    document.getElementById("totalCoffee").innerHTML = prettify(totalCoffee);

    obj.css('position','absolute');
    obj.offset({left: e.pageX-10, top: e.pageY-25});

    obj.animate({"top": "-=80px"}, 1000, "linear", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });     
});
```

and it works great and gives me a popup, but how the hell do i make it an image?

I have tried creating a div, putting an image inside that div and instead of calling "clone" calling on the div...

Am i on the right track?

Example of what i want from cookie clicker - http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

my game so far - retiredgamers.net/

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/edznycyy/6/

Comment: you can use `show()` and `hide()` if you want to hide it and show it, if that's what you want?

Comment: Can we see you html @MIke?

Comment: share you html with this question and create a with your code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: NO problem, here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/edznycyy/6/

Comment: So is it something like that you want? http://s8dev.org/cc.html

Comment: no sorry, but i appreciate any help...what im after is clearer on cookie clicker - http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

when you click the cookie a small cookie appears where your cursor is and breaks away.

at the moment i have a +1 appear when i click, but i would like an an image to appear aswell. like a small png around 25x25px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a lot of ways you could do this. To keep things as close to what you have now as possible here's what I would do...essentially just create 2 elements the first being your numbers and the second being the image, make sure the number is above the image using css's `z-index`, then animate them both in tandem:

Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edznycyy/9/)

**HTML changes:**

```
<img title = "" id="myImg" src="http://blog.beautyfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Coffee_iStock_000006160362Medium.jpg" style="display:none" width="30" height="30">
```

**Javascript changes:**

```
$("#coffeeButton").click(function(e) {

    var obj = $("#clone").clone(); //im guessing you chose to use clone here to make it easier to work with the object, so I did the same for the image
    var img = $("#myImg").clone(); 

    $("body").append(obj);
    $("body").append(img);

    obj.html("+"+ cookRate);
    coffee += cookRate;
    totalCoffee += cookRate;
    document.getElementById("coffee").innerHTML = prettify(coffee);
    document.getElementById("totalCoffee").innerHTML = prettify(totalCoffee);

    obj.css('position','absolute'); 
    obj.css('z-index', '2');
    img.css('position','absolute');
    img.show();

    obj.offset({left: e.pageX-10, top: e.pageY-25});
    img.offset({left: e.pageX-10, top: e.pageY-25});

    obj.animate({"top": "-=80px"}, 1000, "linear", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
    img.animate({"top": "-=80px"}, 1000, "linear", function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: Awesome Code! Thanks :P

I'm going to try and add this in now, Thanks so much for the effort you put in :)

Comment: Glad it helped, you'll surely have to tweak the image, size and maybe even the offset but I think you'll get it going in n time

Comment: BTW, I dont know your knowledge of images, but if you want something that is not square as the image, youll need to use a `png` format image with a clear background

Comment: Already done it :P check it out if you like.

retiredgamers.net

but i am still adjusting the size and offset

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to the trouble of doing it your self, you can use a jquery plugin that does it quite easily. I am sure there is a lot more in the,

Here is what i found!

[Here is the demo page for full-screan popup plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Fullscreen-Popup-Windows)

```
....
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fullscreen-popup.js"></script>
....

<a class="open-popup" href="#popup">Open popup</a>

...

<div id="popup" style="display: none; width: 640px">
  ...
</div>

<script>

    $(function() {
      $(".open-popup").fullScreenPopup({
        // Options
      });
    });

</script>
```

[Example is from here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Fullscreen-Popup-Windows.html) and [you can download the plugin from here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/download/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Fullscreen-Popup-Windows.zip) and [a list that contains many more](http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/popup/)

Comment: OP is not asking for a popup in that sense, he's asking for a small image to popup on the screen when the user clicks :)

Comment: Thanks, That is a cool plugin that may help me in another project im working on, but yes in this instance Delighted is correct. Thanks for your help everyone :P

Comment: @DelighterD0d any chance you can have a look at my code and see why the farmCookRate and the 3 upgrade totals revert back to their default until you click and update them. I have them set to refresh every 100ms and still they don't? any ideas?